# Urllib.request doesn't work on python 3. How can I use beautifulsoup?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to learn how to scrape a website and I keep bumping into urllib.request, which doesn't work for me.

```
import urllib.request
import bs4 as bs
sauce = urllib.request.urlopen('https://www.goat.com/collections/just-dropped').read()
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(sauce, 'lxml')
print(soup)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/)

```
import requests
import bs4 as bs
sauce = requests.get('https://www.goat.com/collections/just-dropped').text
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(sauce, 'lxml')
print(soup)
```

Comment: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests'

Comment: click on the link I left in the solution. You need to install it

Answer (score 0):

You have to to set User-Agent header, but unfortunately the page is dynamic content and you have to Use selenium

```
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
import bs4 as bs

req = Request('https://www.goat.com/collections/just-dropped')
req.add_header('User-Agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:56.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/56.0')
sauce = urlopen(req).read()

soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(sauce, 'lxml')
print(soup)
```

using Selenium, to use it you need to install, Selenium, Chrome and chromedriver

```
pip install selenium
pip install chromedriver-binary
```

the code

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
import chromedriver_binary  # Adds chromedriver binary to path

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://www.goat.com/collections/just-dropped')

# wait until the product rendered
products = WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(
    lambda d: d.find_element_by_css_selector('.goat-clean-product-template ')
)

for p in products:
    name = p.get_attribute('title')
    url = p.get_attribute('href')
    print('%s: %s' % (name, url))
```

Answer (score 0):

As said before, you can use the [`requests`](http://pypi.org/project/requests) library really really to fetch a page content.

First of all you have to install `requests` and `bs4` via `pip`. This will resolve the `ModuleNotFoundError` you are getting.

```
pip install bs4
pip install requests
```

Then he is your code for getting data:

```
import requests 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
sauce = requests.get('https://www.goat.com/collections/just-dropped')
soup = BeautifulSoup(sauce.text, 'lxml')
print(soup)
```

Comment: you are a lovely human being thank you

Comment: @TudorPopica, glad it helped you.